# XtraGridView does not save the last row to my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, devexpress

I have this weird problem with my code,XtraGridView does not save the last row,this is my code to add coulmns to datagrid

```
        void CreateDataTable()
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Le Nom");
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantité");
        dt.Columns.Add("Longueur");
        dt.Columns.Add("Largeur");
        dt.Columns.Add("Poids Total");
        dt.Columns.Add("Projet");
        dt.Columns.Add("Localisation");
        dt.Columns.Add("Fournisseur");
        dt.Columns.Add("Date");
        dt.Columns.Add("IDNom");
        dt.Columns.Add("IDProjet");
        dt.Columns.Add("IDLocalisation");
        dt.Columns.Add("IDFournisseur");
        gridControl1.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

and this is my code to add data to gridview

```
        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow r = dt.NewRow();

        r[0] = cmbName.Text;
        r[1] = txtQte.Text;
        r[2] = txtLength.Text;
        r[3] = txtWidth.Text;
        r[4] = txtWeight.Text;
        r[5] = cmbProject.Text;
        r[6] = cmbLocation.Text;
        r[7] = cmbProvider.Text;
        r[8] = txtDate.Text;
        r[9] = cmbName.SelectedValue;
        r[10] = cmbProject.SelectedValue;
        r[11] = cmbLocation.SelectedValue;
        r[12] = cmbProvider.SelectedValue;
        dt.Rows.Add(r);
    }
```

and this is my code to save all gridview data to my database

```
        private void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<gridView1.RowCount-1;i++)
        {
                prd.Add_ItemQte(Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "IDNom")), Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "IDFournisseur")),
                Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Quantité")), Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Date")),
                Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Longueur")), Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Largeur")),
                Convert.ToDouble(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Poids Total")), Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "IDLocalisation")), Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "IDProjet")));
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Ajouté avec succès", "Ajustements d'inventaire", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
```

i try to add this code before saving data to my database but did not work for me

```
            if (gridView1.IsEditing)
            gridView1.CloseEditor();
        if (gridView1.FocusedRowModified)
            gridView1.UpdateCurrentRow();
```

if the datagrid have only one row (they do not save any thing)
if the datagrid have more then one row (save all rows except the last one)
when i run the code i do not get any error.
can any one help me or show me where did I go wrong,thanks in advance.

Comment: Your for loop has a logical issue. Either <= gridView1.RowCount OR < gridView1.RowCount - 1. You should be setting a break point and debugging this so you know what your code is doing.

Comment: yes it works when i change it to gridView1.RowCount,but why is that

Comment: Think about your for loop. What happens if there is 1 row and your logic is i < RowCount - 1? Is 0 < 0? Nope. So with a single row you wouldn't update anything. Is 0 <= 0? Yes, so it would update the last row. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop has a logical issue.
Row indices start from 0. So if your gridView has 10 rows, it has a  RowCount of 10(indices 0-9). You are running the loop gridView.RowCount-1. Means you are excluding the last row from your loop(RowCount 9, indices 0-8).

Moreover, I would suggest you loop your datatable rather than looping the gridView to save values to database.

```
for(int i = 0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
{
//your code here
}
```